# How to show popup ads on click in webview using sketchware

Tags: webview, onclick, ads, popupwindow, sketchware

Can someone help me and tell me how to enable popup ads window on click in webview using sketchware

Answer (score 0):

it's a bit tricky to make the WebView interact with the app in sketchware but...you can improvise to work around that...I'm pretty sure there's tons of ways to do it..try this(i can't send an image cause of rep):

1. add webview widget
2. Go to event of webview
3. Click "onPageStarted"
4. Put "If" block
5. in the if block You'll compare the url variable with the url when the button is clicked and if they're equal, then load your ad

and if you don't get it...let me know I'll share a project that can do the same thing